# Rmarkdown to Word - How to change Word's styling in references?

Tags: r, ms-word, r-markdown, officedown

I'm trying to apply Word's 'Citation' style in a document generated by rmarkdown. I see in the output the References section is styled by default somehow. My rmarkdown code is like this:

```
---
output: officedown::rdocx_document
params:
  data_manager: NULL
bibliography: bibliography.bib
link-citations: yes
---

Some content goes here...

# References
<!-- this is where bibliography will appear by default -->
```

I tried this:

```
# References

:::{custom-style="Citation"}
<div id="refs"></div>
:::
```

but it's not working. How can I set the style programatically in this case? Is there a pandoc option I should set somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
# References
<div id="refs" custom-style="Citation"></div>
```